# Is it possible to show text on top of an Arearange chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

```js
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            chart: {
                type: 'arearange',
                zoomType: 'x',
                scrollablePlotArea: {
                    minWidth: 600,
                    scrollPositionX: 1
                }
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Temperature variation by day'
            },

            xAxis: {
                //type: 'datetime',
                accessibility: {
                    rangeDescription: 'Range: Jan 1st 2017 to Dec 31 2017.'
                }
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled:true
                }
            },

            

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
plotOptions: {
          series: {
              //stacking: 'normal',
              borderColor: '#303030',
              color : '#cac9c9',
              lineWidth: 1,
              marker: {
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  lineColor: '#303030'
              }
          },
          dataLabels: {
              useHTML: true,
              enabled: true,
              inside: true,
              align:'left',
              allowDecimals: true,
              formatter: function(){
                  return "SOME_TEXT_INSIDE_HTML_TAG";
              }
            },
        },
                series: [{
                        data: [
                        [0, 10],
                        [0, 10],
                    ],
                    borderColor: 'black',
                            borderWidth: 0.2,
                },
                {
                    data: [
                        [20, 40],
                        [20, 40],
                    ]
                }]

        });
```

Above is the code for an Area range chart. Couple of questions.

1. I just want to show some random text on top of each area. I tried with dataLabels but I doesn't seem to work. Isn't it possible to do so?
2. Yaxis seems to be shown in AreaRange chart when mouse is hovered over the chart. Can it be set to be displayed by default?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code and here is an output: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uqmyjsr9/

1. The `dataLabels` config needs to be nested in the `series` object.

   ```
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          //stacking: 'normal',
          borderColor: '#303030',
          color: '#cac9c9',
          lineWidth: 1,
          marker: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#303030'
          },
          dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: true,
            inside: true,
            align: 'left',
            allowDecimals: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return "SOME_TEXT_INSIDE_HTML_TAG";
            }
          },
        },
      },
   ```
2. I am not sure here - the yAxis is displayed all the time, not only after hovering over the chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But instead of showing the text at 4 points for each area, Can we show the text at the middle of the area chart? ie, currently this text(SOME_TEXT_INSIDE_HTML_TAG) is shown against 20 and 40. Can we align it against 30? Hope you understood what I meant?

Comment: @harry yes, I understand, thanks for the explanation. I think that it will be better to use the SVGRenderer tool to render it as a custom label. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label https://support.highcharts.com/a/solutions/articles/44001706971